# How to use str_repeat to repeat a string from an array giving an index of each loop of the str_repeat

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm trying to concatenate array keys (which are originally a class properties). So what I did is:

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r(array_keys(get_object_vars($addressPark)),TRUE).'</pre>';
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => streetAddress_1
    [1] => street_address_2
    [2] => city_name
    [3] => subdivision_name
    [4] => country_name
)
```

This is how I get the `AddressPark` object's properties names.

```
$arr = array_keys(get_object_vars($addressPark));
$count = count($arr);
```

I want to access the object properties by index, that is why I used array_keys.

```
$props = str_repeat("{$arr[$count-$count]},",$count-2).$arr[$count-1];
echo $props;
```

The results is:

> streetAddress_1,streetAddress_1,streetAddress_1,country_name

It repeats `$arr[0] = 'streetAddress_1'` which is normal because in every loop of the `str_repeat` the index of `$arr` is `$count-$count = 0`.
So what I exactly want `str_repeat` to do is for each loop it goes like: `$count-($count-0),$count-($count-1)` ... `$count-($count-4)`. Without using any other loop to increment the value from (0 to 4).

So is there another way to do it?

Comment: Why don't you just use [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) on the array like this: `implode(',', $arr)`

Comment: What is the result that you want???

Comment: Also, when you say `$count-($count-0)`, that is the same as 0 and the next one is 1. So you could just think about it as the 0th element, 1st element, ... until the 4th element.

Comment: @Andrew implode? I never knew about this [tag:implode],I'll search and see how to use it then.Thanks.

Comment: @AbraCadaver the result should be : streetAddress_1,street_address_2,city_name,subdivision_name,country_name

Comment: @Andrew Worked perfectly, I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use `str_repeat` function directly to copy each of the values out of an array into a string. However there are many ways to achieve this, with the most popular being the `implode()` and `array_keys` functions.

`array_keys` extracts the keys from the array. The following examples will solely concentrate on the other part of the issue which is to concatenate the values of the array.

#### Implode

[implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php): Join array elements with a string

```
string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )
```

Example:

```
<?php
$myArray = ['one','two','three'];

echo implode(',', $myArray); 
// one,two,three

echo implode(' Mississippi;', $myArray); 
// one Mississippi; two Mississippi; three Mississippi;
```

---

#### Foreach

[foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php): The foreach construct provides an easy way to iterate over arrays, objects or traversables.

```
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    ...statement...
```

Example:

```
<?php
$myArray = ['one','two','three'];
$output = '';
foreach ($myArray as $val) {
    $output .= $val . ',';
}
echo $output;
// one,two,three,
```

Notice that on this version we have an extra comma to deal with

```
<?php
echo rtrim($output, ',');
// one,two,three
```

---

#### List

[list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php): Assign variables as if they were an array

```
array list ( mixed $var1 [, mixed $... ] )
```

Example:

```
<?php
$myArray = ['one','two','three'];
list($one, $two, $three) = $myArray;
echo "{$one}, {$two}, {$three}";
// one, two, three
```

Note that on this version you have to know how many values you want to deal with.

---

#### Array Reduce

[array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php): Iteratively reduce the array to a single value using a callback function

```
mixed array_reduce ( array $array , callable $callback [, mixed $initial = NULL ] )
```

Example:

```
<?php
$myArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
echo array_reduce($myArray, function ($carry, $item) {
    return $carry .= $item . ', ';
}, '');
// one, two, three,
```

This method also causes an extra comma to appear.

---

#### While

[while](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php): while loops are the simplest type of loop in PHP.

```
while (expr)
    ...statement...
```

Example:

```
<?php
$myArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
$output = '';
while (!empty($myArray)) {
    $output .= array_shift($myArray);
    $output .= count($myArray) > 0 ? ', ' : '';
}
echo $output;
// one, two, three
```

Notice that we've handled the erroneous comma in the loop. This method is destructive as we alter the original array.

---

#### Sprintf and String Repeat

[sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php): My best attempt of actually using the `str_repeat` function:

```
<?php
$myArray = ['one','two','three'];
echo rtrim(sprintf(str_repeat('%s, ', count($myArray)), ...$myArray), ', ');
// one, two, three
```

Notice that this uses the [splat](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php) operator `...` to unpack the array as arguments for the `sprintf` function.

---

Obviously a lot of these examples are not the best or the fastest but it's good to think out of the box sometimes.

There's probably many more ways and I can actually think of more; using array iterators like `array_walk`, `array_map`, `iterator_apply` and `call_user_func_array` using a referenced variable.

If you can think of any more post a comment below :-)